# ModelMapper Class Not Found Error problem in java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to map Department Class Object To DepartmentDto for that I am creating new object of ModelMapper Class. But somehow it is showing ClassNotFound Error. Please help me on this.

**Below is Department Entity POJO class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_DEPARTMENT")
public class Department {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "DEPT_ID")
private Integer deptid;
@Column(name = "DEPT_NAME")
private String deptname;
@Column(name = "DEPT_HEAD")
private String depthead;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dept",orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

 //getter and setters
}
```

**Department Dto class**

```
public class DepartmentDto {

private String deptname;

private String depthead;

//getter and setters
}
```

**pom.xml file**

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

**Code for creating object of ModelMapper**

```
public List<EmployeeDto> getAllEmp()
{
    List<EmployeeDto> empdto = new ArrayList<EmployeeDto>();

    List<Employee> emplist =   empdao.getAllEmp();


    for(Employee emp : emplist)
    {
        Integer deptid = emp.getDept().getDeptid();
        Department deptartment =   deptdao.findDeptById(deptid);


        ModelMapper model = new ModelMapper();
        DepartmentDto deptdto = new DepartmentDto();
        model.map(deptartment, deptdto);


        EmployeeDto edto  = new EmployeeDto();
        edto.setId(emp.getId());
        edto.setDesignation(emp.getDesignation());
        edto.setEmail(emp.getEmail());
        edto.setMobile(emp.getMobile());
        edto.setName(emp.getName());
        edto.setSalary(emp.getSalary());



        empdto.add(edto);

    }

    return empdto;
}
```

**Error**
[image]

Comment: clkean your project and reinstall it again

Comment: Are you sure that this is not a build maven build issue? Because I don't see any problem with the code.

Comment: Thanks got it solved!! I cleaned and reninstalled it again